# Pivot with sum aggregation

Tags: sql

I have a table as tab1 and I want to have result like tab-2 pivot on netproduct sales (NPS) for each salesperson, and month 1 value in jan, similarly month 2 value in feb and month 3 in march.

FY is sum of jan+feb+mar (NPS)

```
DECLARE @TAB1 TABLE
(
   YEAR  NUMERIC (4, 0),
   MONTH NUMERIC (4, 0),
   SMC   CHAR (1),
   SG    CHAR (1),
   SPN   VARCHAR (10),
   ISGR  FLOAT,
   NPS   FLOAT
) 


INSERT @TAB1
SELECT 2015,    2,  1,  'C',    11, 1,  232745.61 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2015,    1,  1,  'C',    11, 1,  246328.04 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2015,    3,  1,  'C',    11, 1,  447488.01
```

Expected output:

```
YEAR|MONTH|SMC|SG|SPN|ISGR|JAN      |FEB      |MAR      |FY
2015|1    |1  |C |11 |1   |246328.04|232745.61|447488.01|926561.66
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query :

```
SELECT YEAR,SMC,SMC,SG,SPN,ISGR,[1] AS [JAN],[2] AS [FEB],[3] AS [MAR] , [1] + [2] + [3] AS [FY]
FROM @TAB1
PIVOT
(   
    SUM(NPS)
    FOR [MONTH] IN ([1],[2],[3])
)AS pvt
```

Note : it doesn't include [Month] column in Result as it is used for pivoting.

Comment: i am sorry, but this is not giving correct result. many null are appearing instead of correct value. Value available in only one column.        JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUNE JULY AUG SEP OCT NOV
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 793498.2. any suggestion.

Comment: This is working fine. check this sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1562 . if you want to add more months then it should be added in the list `FOR [MONTH] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])` and select those similar to how I selected `[1] AS [JAN]`.

Comment: Hi Deepak, i did something like this.SELECT 
YEAR,
SMC,
SG,
SPN,
[ISGR],
[1] AS [JAN],
[2] AS [FEB],
[3] AS [MAR] , 
[4] as [APR],
[5] AS [MAY],
[6] AS [JUNE],
[7] AS [JULY],
[8] AS [AUG],
[9] AS SEP,
[10] AS OCT,
[11] AS NOV,
[12] AS DEC,
[1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10] + [11] + [12]  AS [FY]
FROM TEMP
PIVOT
(   
    SUM([NPS])
    FOR [MONTH] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
)AS pvt,   but getting NULL in month field , please suggest.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with your data for which your query is returning NULL for Months, so that I can debug more accurately? because it should have worked.